# MDT Application Installs within LiteTocuh.vbs but not initial deployment

Tags: deployment, application, automated-install, mdt, silent

Ok I am having a weird issue with MDT.

I have an application that I am trying to install with a batch file.
This application requires a .iss file to be silently installed. Here is what the batch file holds: `Application.exe /s /f1"PathToISS.iss"`
Here is the quiet install command I am giving MDT: `cmd.exe /c batchFileName.bat`

I have a VM enviroment setup for testing before putting it on our actual MDT server.
The application installs fine within my VM but here is the weird issue.

When PXE booting and selecting the application MDT does not install this application. MDT gives a return code of: -2147213312 (I have tried contacting the company who created the software only to be told that they will not give us any information/help because they do not support MDT or Silent installations)

We have setup a TaskSequence that allows us to install applications without having to go through the whole boot sequence again. When opening the `LiteTouch.vbs` script we select the task sequence to only install applications, We select the same application that failed during the initial deployment and what do you know it installs perfectly fine......

My question is why does the application install just fine when selecting the `LiteTocuh.vbs` Script and not within the initial deployment?
Why does the application install fine within my VM and not our actual environment?

Thanks.

NOTE: The reason I am using a batch file is because this is the only way I could get this application to install correctly on the actual MDT server (not the VM).

Comment: Hi JOhn,

Welcome to Serverfault :)
Does this help with your silent install?
https://www.itninja.com/question/install-shield-exit-code-2147213312-sccm-package

Comment: Does your VM have a base (clean) install and your actual environment have a security system?

Comment: @ElliotLabsLLC both clean installs. that link did not help. I was able to install silently using the commands in the link through the LiteTouch.vbs but not initial deployment once again.